# How to fix the batch size in keras subclassing model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

In tf.keras functional API, I can fix the batch size like below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(64, 64, 3), batch_size=1)    # I can fix batch size like this
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(3, 3, strides=2, padding="same", activation="relu")(inputs)
outputs = x
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name="custom")
```

My question is, how do I can fix the batch size when I use the keras subclassing approach?

Comment: what do you mean by keras subclassing approach ?

Comment: @Gevezo https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models

Comment: Can you advise why you prefer to fix the batch size inside `keras.Input` rather than setting the batch size of the dataset?

Comment: @learner For running model on mobile gpu. If symbolic tensor has `None` value in tensor.shape, tflite converted model is failed on gpu delegate. To eliminate this problem, model input shape should be fixed including batch size.

Answer (score 0):

One way of dealing with your parameters indirectly (when there's no reach to it) is using `tf.keras.backend` access. In this case, tf defines the input format through call function:

```
def call(self, inputs):
    z_mean, z_log_var = inputs
    batch = tf.shape(z_mean)[0]
    dim = tf.shape(z_mean)[1]
    epsilon = tf.keras.backend.random_normal(shape=(batch, dim))
    return z_mean + tf.exp(0.5 * z_log_var) * epsilon
```

And then iterates over each batch

```
for step, x_batch_train in enumerate(train_dataset):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        reconstructed = vae(x_batch_train)
        # Compute reconstruction loss
        loss = mse_loss_fn(x_batch_train, reconstructed)
        loss += sum(vae.losses)  # Add KLD regularization loss

    grads = tape.gradient(loss, vae.trainable_weights)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, vae.trainable_weights))

    loss_metric(loss)

    if step % 100 == 0:
        print("step %d: mean loss = %.4f" % (step, loss_metric.result())
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I expect to eliminate the `None` in input shape. Unfortunately, your method still has `(None, H, W ,C)` input shape.

Comment: Could you give more detail as to the code you've been using so far ? I thought this should allow the access you want to have to "batch_size".